# Variability in the fitted values

Tags: regression, self-study, mixed-model, variance, diagnostic

For a dataset, I have fitted a model. The fitted or predicted values have less variability than the observed values. What does it imply?

Comment: That your model explains a part of the observed variability.

Comment: @Sergio Is it bad indication that the fitted values are not as spread as observed values?

Comment: In the 1880's, Francis Galton discovered this was a universal phenomenon.  It is part of his theory of "regression to the mean."  He illustrated it with his celebrated [quincunx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine).

Comment: Variability of observed values: $\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2$. Variability of fitted values: $\sum(\hat{y}_i-\bar{y})^2$. Variability around your model: $\sum(y_i-\hat{y})^2$. Since
$$\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2=\sum(y_i-\hat{y})^2+\sum(\hat{y}_i-\bar{y})^2$$
the variability of fitted values can never be greater than the variability of observed values, and they can be equal only if you model explains absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Sergio the only citation I've found that makes your sound argument is Farmer 2016, doi 10.1002/2016WR019129.  I have looked (and looked, for hours…)!  Suggestions pls?  Does the concept have a name?  I need cites for a skeptical reviewer for (1) the 'never can be greater' concept above, (2) if the predictions' variance IS higher than benchmark then at least one coefficient is overestimated, and (3) if the coefficient in a single-driver linear regression is misestimated by a multiplier k, then the variance of the predictions will change by a factor of k squared.

Comment: @whuber, same request as above?  I tried Galton per your comment but didn't yet find what I need.  I understand that the basic issue is that a deterministic prediction doesn't reproduce the variability represented by each source observation's error term but my explanation isn't sufficient without citations.

Comment: @InColorado: The concept has a name, and it is "analysis of variance". See Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter & Li, _Applied Linear Statistical Models_, §2.7; Weisberg, _Appplied Linear Regression_, §2.6; Draper & Smith, _Applied Regression Analysis_, §1.3; Graybill & Iyer, _Regression Analysis_, §3.8 etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to be expected that the variability in fitted values is less than the variability in observed values. The lower the variability in fitted values, the "better" the model. When you fit a model to data you are trying to "explain" the variability in the data. There will almost always be some random error due to natural variation, or measurement error, for example, so your model can never be expected to explain all the variation. In the comments, sergio has put it very well:

> Variability of observed values: $\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2$. Variability of fitted values: $\sum(\hat{y}_i-\bar{y})^2$. Variability around your model: $\sum(y_i-\hat{y})^2$. Since
> $$ \sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2=\sum(y_i-\hat{y})^2+\sum(\hat{y}_i-\bar{y})^2$$
> the variability of fitted values can never be greater than the variability of observed values, and they can be equal only if you model explains absolutely nothing